# JavaFX Обновление Vbox при добавлении содержимого

Tags: javafx

Есть окно с кнопкой "Добавить", по нажатию по которую открывается FileChooser. После выделения нескольких файлов в VBox добавляются "карточки" (экземпляры класса Controller) с описанием этих файлов. Проблема в том, что они добавляются все одновременно, а я хочу, чтобы они отображались в интерфейсе по мере обработки каждого файла (добавление в интерфейс в конце каждой итерации цикла).

```
@FXML
private void addHandle() throws IOException {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    List<File> list = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);

    DevFile devFile;
    
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        devFile = new DevFile(device, list.get(i), type);
        Controller controller = createDevFileCard(devFile);

        vbox.getChildren().add(controller.getRoot());
    }
}

private Controller createDevFileCard(DevFile devFile) throws IOException {
    loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/devFiles/editor_element.fxml"));
    pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setElement(devFile);

    return controller;
}
```

Пробовал запускать цикл в отдельном потоке и оттуда вызывать отрисовку Controller в потоке JavaFX через Platform.runlater(), но не получилось. Сначала создаются экземпляры класса Controller, затем они добавляются в vbox, и только затем все разом уже отображаются на экране. Аналогичная проблема возникла и с удалением "карточек" из VBox - удаляются все разом.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы:

1. Создать отдельный поток, перенести логику в него, создать в нем элемент, который будет добавлен в vbox
2. Создать статичный метод, который возвращается в поток JavaFX, и в нем уже добавляет в vbox созданный элемент

   ```
   //метод JavaFX класса
   private void addHandle(){
       FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
       List<File> list = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);

       AddNewFiles thread = new AddNewFiles(list, this);
       thread.start();
   }

   //поток, в котором реализована логика
   private class AddNewCard extends Thread{
       Controller mainController;
       List<File> list;

       public AddNewFiles(List<File> list, Controller mainController){
           this.list = list;
           this.mainController = mainController;
       }

       @Override
       public void run(){
           //заполняем карточки контентом
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
               //какая-то логика

               //создаем элемент, который будем помещать в vbox
               ElementController elementController = createCard();
               //вызываем статичный метод класса, содержащего vbox, передаем в него наш элемент
               Controller.addCardToVBox(mainController, elementController);
           }
       }
   }

   private static void addCardToVBox(Controller mainController, ElementController controller) {
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       mainController.addToVbox(controller);
                   }
               };
               Platform.runLater(updater);
           }
       });

       thread.setDaemon(true);
       thread.start();
   }

   public void addToVbox(ElementController controller){
       vbox.getChildren().add(controller.getRoot());
   }
   ```